# How to get object's class name by related_name in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 2 classes:

```
class Album:
  title = models.TextField()

class Image:
  title = models.TextField()
  rel = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name="images", editable=False)
```

Now I have an empty object:

```
album = Album()
```

How do I get the name of the class of the object that's referenced via related_name 'images'? I need to get it as 'Image'.

Calling

```
repr(Album.images.__class__.__name__)
```

returns

```
ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor
```

that is not what I need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `__name__` property,

Comment: It won't work: ***AttributeError: 'ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute '__name__'***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using object:

```
album.images.model.__name__
```

Using class:

```
Album.images.related.model.__name__
```

Comment: nope ((( returns ***'ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'model'***